# call attributes inside a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I have script like this.

```
map.addMarker({
 lat: data[x]['lat'],
 lng: data[x]['lng'],
 icon: iconUsed,
 click: function() {
  alert(lat)
 },
 infoWindow: {
  content: popupMaps.join(''),
 });
```

is it possible to call 'lat' parameter inside addMarker() ?
i mean, when i click the marker, it will alerting me the lat parameter itself.
i dont know what is going wrong, if i use alert(data[x]['lat']) it will always show me the last increment number in 'x' looping.

hope someone knows what i means
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing this in a loop. If so, move the actual creation of the entry to its own function that you *call* with the `lat` and `lng`:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, iconUsed) {
    map.addMarker({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        icon: iconUsed,
        click: function() {
            alert(lat);
    },
    infoWindow: {
        content: popupMaps.join(''),
    });
}
```

You'll want to define that function in the same scope where `map` and `popupMaps` are.

Then calling it from your loop:

```
addMarker(data[x]['lat'], data[x]['lng'], iconUsed);
```

That way, your `click` callback closes over the `lat` and `lng` arguments to `addMarker`, which don't change, rather than over `data` and `x`, which change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got what you need, maybe this

```
var lat = data[x]['lat'];
map.addMarker({
 lat: lat,
 lng: data[x]['lng'],
 icon: iconUsed,
 click: function() {
  alert(lat)
 },
 infoWindow: {
  content: popupMaps.join(''),
 });
```